# Changing to 'editable' after the calendar has been loaded in Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar and I wish to be able to allow administrators to be able to exit editable mode to perform other actions on the calendar. How can I dynamically change this setting of full calendar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has no way to directly change that setting on the move, because then I could easily change the setting myself. The way you change if an "EVENT" is editable for an admin, you set this in the event object as a parameter just like you would the color. This stops someone from calling the edit function from fullcalendar if they had one.

You will now have to do all your testing for the admin serverside or if you load the data static then your event object would look something like this

```
  events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        editable: true
                    }
    ]
```

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/